# c# simple background thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, background, task

I am looking for a simple way to do a task in background, then update something (on the main thread) when it completes. It's in a low level 'model' class so I can't call InvokeOnMainThread as I don't have an NSObject around. I have this method:

```
public void GetItemsAsync(Action<Item[]> handleResult)
{
  Item[] items=null;
  Task task=Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
    items=this.CreateItems(); // May take a second or two
  });
  task.ContinueWith(delegate
  {
    handleResult(items);
  }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

This seems to work OK, but

1) Is this the best (simplest) way?

2) I'm worried about the local variable:

```
Item{} items=null
```

What stops that disappearing when the method returns before the background thread completes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your method slightly violates a [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), because it doing too much.

First of all I suggest to change `CreateItems` to return `Task` instead of wrapping it in the `GetItemsAsync`:

```
public Task<Item[]> CreateItems(CancellationToken token)
{
   return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
     // obtaining the data...
     {});
}
```

[CancellationToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx) is optional but can help you if you able to cancel this long running operation.

With this method you can remove `GetItemsAsync` entirely because its so simple to handle results by your client without passing this delegate:

```
// Somewhere in the client of your class
var task = yourClass.CreateItems(token);
task.ContinueWith(t => 
 // Code of the delegate that previously
 // passed to GetItemsAsync method
 {}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Using this approach you'll get more clear code with only one responsibility. [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) class itself is a perfect tool for representing asynchronous operation as a [first class object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen). Using proposed technique you can easily mock you current implementation with a fake behavior for unit testing without changing your clients code.

Comment: Thanks, thats better in principle. Can even remove the task variable

yourClass.CreateItems(token).ContinueWith(t => 
{
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

Pity we need"TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()" though.

I want the simplest possible API for the client so its either:

1) yourClass.GetItemsAsync(delegate(Item[] items)
   { 
     // Do something with items
   });

or

2) yourClass.CreateItems().ContinueWith(t => 
{
  // Do something with t.Result
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

So I still need the GetItemsAsync method really.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But GetItemsAsync is much more clear than previous solution in terms of OO principles and Task-based programming. For example, using proposed technique it would be much easier migrate to await/async features C# 5.0. In terms of OOP this solution is more simple because its not trying to invent the wheel.
And do not forget a testability: in this case you can easily obtain this task from mock implementation and test any corner case of you clients code.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
    public void GetItemsAsync(Action<Item[]> handleResult)
    {
        int Id = 11;
        Task<Item[]> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CreateItems(Id)); // May take a second or two
        task.ContinueWith(t => handleResult(t.Result), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
```

Comment: Lovely, thanks. But personally, I prefer @laszlokiss88 answer - it's also just 2 lines (essentially) and seems simpler to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine.

It's a perfect example of when to use `async / await` if you can use C# 5, but if not, you have to write it as you have done with continuations.

The `items` variable is captured in your lambdas, so that's fine too.

When you write a lambda that uses an outside variable, the C# compiler creates a class that contains the variable. This is called a closure and means you can access the variable inside your lambda.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply :) I'd almost given up with SO after my last question about iOS APIs to find out data traffic is completely ignored. I guess it's good for some things and not others.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nicer soultion:

```
    public void GetItemsAsync(Action<Item[]> handleResult)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew<Item[]>(() =>
        {
            return this.CreateItems(); // May take a second or two
        });

        task.ContinueWith(delegate
        {
            handleResult(task.Result);
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
```

Comment: @Bbx: you don't have Result feature because you should change the code to: Task<Item[]> task = Task.Factory....

Comment: Thanks, yea I just realised that after I posted my comment :)